# Question about this proof that <k>/<kn> is isomorphic to Zn, for integers k,n.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

Proof I found:

Because $\left<k\right>$ is cyclic, all elements in $\left<k\right>$ are of the form $mk$ for $m ∈\mathbb Z$. So all elements in $\left<k\right>/\left<kn\right>$ are of the form $mk+\left<kn\right>=m(k + \left<kn\right>)$. Therefore $\left<k\right>/\left<kn\right>$ is cyclic and it is generated by $k+\left<kn\right>$. So it suffices to check the order of $k+\left<kn\right>$.
Note that $n(k + \left<kn\right>)=nk +\left<kn\right> = \left<kn\right>$ and for $0 < m < n$, $m(k + \left<kn\right>)\neq \left<kn\right>$.
Therefore $|k + \left<kn\right>| = n$ and $\left<k\right>/\left<kn\right>$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_n$.

My question: 
Why is it true that $mk + \left<kn\right> = m(k + \left<kn\right>)$? if we take the case of <3> and <12>, then it seems we would be claiming that <3>/<12> = 3m + <12> = m(3 + <12>). But that implies that <12> = m<12>. Why is that true? If <12> = {0, 12, -12, 24, -24,...} it seems scaling that set by an integer m would change the set. Can someone please explain what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the operation in factor group $G/H$ is defined as : $(aH)(bH)=abH$.
So $(aH)^2=a^2H$. In additive notation this is $2(a+H)=2a+H$. This is what the person providing the solution probably meant.